# How to update a scatter plot animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-animation

I tried to write a simple script which updates a scatter plot for every timestep `t`. I wanted to do it as simple as possible. But all it does is to open a window where I can see nothing. The window just freezes. It is maybe just an small error, but I can not find it.

The the `data.dat` has the format

```
                x      y
Timestep 1      1      2
                3      1
Timestep 2      6      3
                2      1
```

(the file contains just the numbers)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

# Load particle positioins
with open('//home//user//data.dat', 'r') as fp:
    particles = []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.split() 
        if line:
            line = [float(i) for i in line]
            particles.append(line)

T = 100
numbParticles = 2

x, y = np.array([]), np.array([])

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
for t in range(T):
    plt.clf()
    for k in range(numbP):
            x = np.append(x, particles[numbParticles*t+k][0])
            y = np.append(y, particles[numbParticles*t+k][1])
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(1)
    x, y = np.array([]), np.array([])
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest, cleanest way to make an animation is to use the [`matplotlib.animation`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html) module, as shown in this [Matplotlib Animation Tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

Since a scatter plot returns a `matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`, the way to update it is to call its `set_offsets` method. You can pass it an array of shape (N, 2) or a list of N 2-tuples -- each 2-tuple being an `(x,y)` coordinate.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

T = 100
numbParticles = 2
particles = np.random.random((T,numbParticles)).tolist()
x, y = np.array([]), np.array([])

def init():
    pathcol.set_offsets([[], []])
    return [pathcol]

def update(i, pathcol, particles):
    pathcol.set_offsets(particles[i])
    return [pathcol]

fig = plt.figure()
xs, ys = zip(*particles)
xmin, xmax = min(xs), max(xs)
ymin, ymax = min(ys), max(ys)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))
pathcol = plt.scatter([], [], s=100)

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func=init, fargs=(pathcol, particles),
                     interval=1000, frames=T, blit=True, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

The loop is inside [`FuncAnimation()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html#funcanimation), so you don't see it. You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/animation.py) if you like (actually there is no loop there, but an iterator), but you can also just accept that seen from the outside `FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1000, frames=100)` will just call the function `update` every 1000 ms and increment `i` by 1 up to the number given by `frames`.

Comment: `pathcol.set_offsets([[], []])` → `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. You can do it simply by using this script. I tried to keep it simple:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Helps me to get the data from the file I want to plot
N = 0

# Load particle positioins
with open('//home//user//data.dat', 'r') as fp:
    particles = []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.split() 
        particles.append(line)

# Create new Figure and an Axes which fills it.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=True)
border = 100
ax.set_xlim(-border, border), ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_ylim(-border, border), ax.set_yticks([])

# particle data
p = 18 # number of particles
myPa = np.zeros(p, dtype=[('position', float, 2)])

# Construct the scatter which we will update during animation
scat = ax.scatter(myPa['position'][:, 0], myPa['position'][:, 1])

def update(frame_number):
    # New positions
    myPa['position'][:] = particles[N*p:N*p+p]

    # Update the scatter collection, with the new colors, sizes and positions.
    scat.set_offsets(myPa['position'])
    increment()

def increment():
    global N
    N = N+1

# Construct the animation, using the update function as the animation director.
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Not particularly useful without sample data.