# Scatter animation in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-animation

I am attempting to animate a scatter plot in Python 3.6 (in Spyder IDE), for which there are several tutorials/examples ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot), [b](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686697/python-matplotlib-update-scatter), and many others), however my update function is somehow receiving a very different set of coordinates from what I think I'm providing.

The following is a reduced example code wherein 4 points proceed toward the center.  I plot it twice, first as a line, second as an animation.  The line plot looks right, but the animation shows very different behavior, both in terms of the locations of the points and their trajectories.  I infer that I'm incorrectly supplying coordinate information to the update function, but I cannot seem to determine why/how.

I can supply figures showing what does vs. should happen, though I'll simply supply this sample code for now for brevity's sake.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

npt=4
ntime=101
solx=np.zeros((npt,ntime))
soly=np.zeros((npt,ntime))
solx[0,0:]=np.linspace(0,40,ntime)
solx[1,0:]=solx[0,0:];
solx[2,0:]=100-solx[0,0:];
solx[3,0:]=solx[2,0:]
soly[0,0:]=np.linspace(0,80,ntime)
soly[1,0:]=200-soly[0,0:]
soly[2,0:]=soly[0,0:]
soly[3,0:]=soly[1,0:]


#%% Plots
colord=mpl.cm.gist_ncar(np.linspace(0,0.9,npt))
of2,oa2=plt.subplots(1)
for cnt in range(0,npt): oa2.plot(solx[cnt,0:],soly[cnt,0:],c=colord[cnt])

of3,oa3=plt.subplots()
osc3=oa3.scatter(solx[0:,0],soly[0:,0],c=colord,marker='+')
def aninit():
    osc3.set_offsets(np.stack((solx[0:,0],soly[0:,0]),axis=0))
    return osc3,
def aniupdate(i):
    osc3.set_offsets(np.stack((solx[0:,i],soly[0:,i]),axis=0))
    return osc3,

ani=anim.FuncAnimation(of3,aniupdate,init_func=aninit,frames=range(0,ntime),interval=100,blit=True,repeat=True,repeat_delay=1000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace

```
np.stack((solx[0:,0],soly[0:,0]),axis=0)
np.stack((solx[0:,i],soly[0:,i]),axis=0)
```

with:

```
list(zip(solx[0:,0],soly[0:,0]))
list(zip(solx[0:,i],soly[0:,i]))
```

or (if you want to use numpy arrays instead of lists:

```
np.array([solx[0:,0],soly[0:,0]]).T
np.array([solx[0:,i],soly[0:,i]]).T
```

in the `aninit()` and `aniupdate(i)` functions the behaviour should be as expected.

Here's the code I used to make the plots:

```
def aninit():
    offsetlist = np.array([solx[0:,0],soly[0:,0]]).T
    osc3.set_offsets(offsetlist)
    return osc3,

def aniupdate(i):
    offsetlist = np.array([solx[0:,i],soly[0:,i]]).T
    osc3.set_offsets(offsetlist)
    return osc3,
```

[image]

#### References:

- [Rain Simulation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/rain.html)
- [old_animation example code: dynamic_collection.py](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/old_animation/dynamic_collection.html?highlight=set_offsets)